# Getting data from mysql query based on Date duration

Tags: php, mysql

I Have one mysql table with five fields. fields are alert_id, creation_time, assigned_to, alert_duration, alert_body. In a single query i need to get alert_body based on

1. assigned_to(where assigned_to ='401').
2. current date in between creation_time and creation_time + alert_duration

alert_duration is numbers of days. So In my query i need to fetch the data only if the current date in between that time gap(creation_time to creation_time +3days).

Example:

current Date: 2/9/2015

creation_time: 31/08/2015

alert_duration : 3

So if i execute the query on or before 2/9/2015, should get the result with data. But in case i execute the query by tomorrow, then query will give empty result.

Here i add the sql format also

**Table structure for table `tbl_alerts`**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_alerts` (
  `alert_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
  `assigned_to` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `alert_duration` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `alert_body` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`alert_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

**Dumping data for table `tbl_alerts`**

INSERT INTO `tbl_alerts` (`alert_id`, `creation_time`, `assigned_to`, `alert_duration`, `alert_body`) VALUES
('1000001', '2015-09-01 23:26:41.000000', '401', 3, 'good morning, have a nic day'),
('1000002', '2015-08-15 08:31:37.000000', '401', 2, 'History papers will be distributed on Friday.');

Please help me , Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a single query i need to get alert_body

```sql
select alert_body from my_table
```

> based on
>
> 1. assigned_to(where assigned_to ='401').

```sql
where assigned_to = '401'
```

> 2. current date in between creation_time and creation_time + alert_duration

```sql
and current_date between creation_time and creation_time +
          INTERVAL alert_duration DAY
```

Comment: @BibinJames: You mean, like the solution that's in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the TO_DAYS function

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_alerts 
WHERE 
   assigned_to = '401' 
  AND
   TO_DAYS(now()) - TO_DAYS(creation_time) <= alert_duration
```

Not sure if the comparision is with the alert_duration or with the hardcoded 3 days